# How restart a count for a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a answer due to I tried with `row_number`, `iif` and  `case` when but I can't count the column `Conteo` as I need.

I have this table

| Fecha | Cliente | Gestion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X1 | 1 |
| 2023-05-01 | X2 | 1 |
| 2023-05-02 | X1 | null |
| 2023-05-02 | X2 | null |
| 2023-05-03 | X1 | null |
| 2023-05-03 | X2 | 1 |
| 2023-05-04 | X1 | 1 |
| 2023-05-04 | X2 | null |

Column `Conteo` has 0 when gestion is 1 and has to increment if gestion is 0 until find a 1 again and restart a count. I tried with

```
    iff(gestion is not null, 
        0, 
        row_number() over (partition by cliente, fecha order by cliente fecha) as Conteo
```

but it doesn't restart the count. This is a short example, due to i have more than 2 cliente and date. Gestion is only 1 or null.

This should be the result:

| Fecha | Cliente | Gestion | Conteo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-01 | X2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-02 | X1 | null | 1 |
| 2023-05-02 | X2 | null | 1 |
| 2023-05-03 | X1 | null | 2 |
| 2023-05-03 | X2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-04 | X1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-04 | X2 | null | 1 |

Code if you need an example:

```
-- drop table Example
 
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    Fecha date NOT NULL,
    Cliente varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Gestion int NULL,
    Conteo int NULL
);

INSERT INTO Example (Fecha, Cliente, Gestion, Conteo)
VALUES ('2023-05-01', 'X1', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-01', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-02', 'X1', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-02', 'X2', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-03', 'X1', null, 2),
       ('2023-05-03', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-04', 'X1', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-04', 'X2', null, 1)
```

Comment: You didn't tell us if cliente has any importance and what the result should be. It is not understood from your story telling.

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands", that's basically what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a twist on the classic gaps and islands:

```sql
DECLARE @Example TABLE (
    Fecha DATE NOT NULL
    ,Cliente VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
    ,Gestion INT NULL
    ,Conteo INT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @Example (Fecha, Cliente, Gestion, Conteo)
VALUES ('2023-05-01', 'X1', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-01', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-02', 'X1', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-02', 'X2', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-03', 'X1', null, 2),
       ('2023-05-03', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-04', 'X1', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-04', 'X2', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-05', 'X1', NULL, 1),
       ('2023-05-06', 'X1', NULL, 2),
       ('2023-05-05', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-06', 'X2', 1, 0),
       ('2023-05-07', 'X2', null, 1),
       ('2023-05-08', 'X2', null, 2);

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN gestion = 1
            THEN 0
        ELSE row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY cliente
                ,grouping ORDER BY fecha
                )
    END AS ConteoNew
    ,Conteo AS expected
    ,Fecha
    ,cliente
    ,Gestion
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(Counter) OVER (
            PARTITION BY cliente ORDER BY fecha
            ) AS grouping
        ,*
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN LAG(ISNULL(Gestion, 0)) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY Cliente ORDER BY Fecha
                        ) <> ISNULL(Gestion, 0)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS Counter
            ,*
        FROM @Example
        ) AS x
    ) AS x
```

The method is usually following:

- Create a flag 1 or 0 depending if previous row is same as current one. I usually set flag 1 if previous differs, this simplifies handling of first row which never has a previous one.
- Summarize the flag. This creates groups of rows, with same Gestion value.
- Do what you need to do with the groups. In your case, you want to increment each time Gestion is not 1, for this i use ROW_NUMBER(). When Gestion is 0, i just set Conteo to 0.

Results from this:

```
ConteoNew   expected    Fecha   cliente Gestion
0   0   2023-05-01  X1  1
1   1   2023-05-02  X1  NULL
2   2   2023-05-03  X1  NULL
0   0   2023-05-04  X1  1
1   1   2023-05-05  X1  NULL
2   2   2023-05-06  X1  NULL
0   0   2023-05-01  X2  1
1   1   2023-05-02  X2  NULL
0   0   2023-05-03  X2  1
1   1   2023-05-04  X2  NULL
0   0   2023-05-05  X2  1
0   0   2023-05-06  X2  1
1   1   2023-05-07  X2  NULL
2   2   2023-05-08  X2  NULL
```

Comment: I edited for clarity only - mostly formatting

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The original format was perfectly fine.   Your format preferences are just that ... YOUR preference.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks, that was I needed, however, I can't use subquery's due to my job policies but I think thas another problem to solve by me haha.

Really appreciate your help! Thanks, again.

Comment: credit to @siggemannen for the work I just did an edit

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a gaps-and-island problem. As I understand it, an island starts every time a `1` is met: we can just model this as a window sum. All that is then left to do is to enumerate records in each island, using `row_number()`:

```
select e.*, 
    row_number() over(partition by cliente, grp order by fecha) - 1 as conteo
from (
    select e.*,
        sum(gestion) over(partition by cliente order by fecha) grp
    from example e
) e
order by fecha, cliente
```

| Fecha | Cliente | Gestion | grp | conteo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 | X1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-01 | X2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-05-02 | X1 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-05-02 | X2 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-05-03 | X1 | *null* | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-05-03 | X2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-05-04 | X1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-05-04 | X2 | *null* | 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rgNlq8cz)

Note that this assumes that `gestion` contains either `1`, `0` or `null`. If different values may appear (but you still ought to reset the counter on `1` only), then we would rephrase the window sum as follows:

```
sum(case when gestion = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by cliente order by fecha) grp
```